# Color Detection withOpenCV 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0

Im using OpenCV 3.4.3, and get this error with my code:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

How I fix this?

```
cv2.putText(img, str(i+1),(x,y+h),font,(0,255,255))
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace? What version of cv2 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the wrong argument. You should pass the fontsize before the color tuple like the following example from docs:

```
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img,'OpenCV',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

This [LINK](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html) explains the OpenCV drawing functions in detail and will be helpful.